# How do I include the zero-cross terms in pandas groupby?

Tags: python, csv, pandas

How do I output a `pandas` groupby result -- **including zero cross-terms** -- to a csv file.

A toy example of exactly what I'm looking for:

I have a `pandas` dataframe that can be approximated as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'], (10, 2)), 
                  columns=['one', 'two'])
```

Which gave me the following:

```
   one  two
0   C   C
1   C   A
2   A   B
3   B   A
4   B   C
5   B   B
6   C   C
7   A   C
8   C   B
9   C   C
```

When I run groupby it works as expected:

```
grouped = df.groupby(['one', 'two']).size()
grouped

one  two
A    B      1
     C      1
B    A      1
     B      1
     C      1
C    A      1
     B      1
     C      3
dtype: int64
```

However, I would like for the "A   A   0" term to be included because I write this to a csv file:

```
grouped.to_csv("test1.csv", header=True)

!cat test1.csv

one,two,0
A,B,1
A,C,1
B,A,1
B,B,1
B,C,1
C,A,1
C,B,1
C,C,3
```

And I want the file to include the line: `A,A,0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with unstack:

`grouped.unstack('two').fillna(0).stack()`

which gives, for example, the following output:

```
one  two
A    A      2
     B      1
     C      1
B    A      0
     B      1
     C      3
C    A      2
     B      0
     C      0
```